# Android Updating/Refreshing UI in a time interval

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity having a listview. and I am receiving some messages from bluetooth and storing to an adapter.I want to display the messages to the listview when it comes. right now I'm restarting the activity manually I want it to be automatic . What I have to do

Comment: I think if you want to periodically updates, you need to use `Handler`.

Comment: Can you show me a code sample.? I am damn new to android

Comment: Look at this article - [Android Handler Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using android AsyncTask Activity. update your list adapter form AyncTask's [doInbackgroung](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method  and on [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) update the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //Your task
    }

},
0,
1000);
```